# How to convert WebDriverIO test project into a self executable file

Tags: javascript, package, exe, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

I have a automation test suite developed in WebDriverIO Javascript. I would like to know if we have an option to convert it into an executable file, so that any one can trigger the test run by double clicking the file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can create a batch file to do this. Clicking on the batch file will run the webdriverio code